# Disable wrapping imports on right margin in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2017.2.1 and Intellij is wrapping my import statements on the right margin when I optimize the imports.

How can I disable that so the imports aren't wrapped anymore?

Comment: Vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152088.

Comment: Thanks also worth noting, I discovered in the meanwhile that I had to uncheck Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java->Wrapping and Braces->Ensure right margin is not exceeded. It has some side-effects, but disables the wrapping of import statements when reformatting.

Answer (score 3):

In Webstorm it's under (maybe it'll help you in other Intellij IDEs too): `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript (or other) -> "Wrapping and Braces" tab -> "ES6 import/export" header` - select `Do not wrap`.